# How can I implement a select list in apex oracle's interactive grid using only sql and what's available in oracle APEX?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, apex

| ID | Material | Material_Num | User | Assign User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | stick | 1111 | Billy Bob | "select list of users" |
| 2 | stone | 1112 | Jane Doe | "select list of users" |
| 3 | rock | 1113 | John Deer | "select list of users" |
| 4 | slab | 1114 |  | "select list of users" |
| 5 | brick | 1115 |  | "select list of users" |

There will be a save button which will update the user column with the value in the assign user column. If the select list can be consolidated under the user column and keep the updated values that would be even better.

These are the steps I have taken so far:

1. Added an interactive grid to the page.
2. Created a query to populate the interactive grid.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       MD.ID,
       MD.MATERIAL,
       MD.MATERIAL_NUMBER,
       FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME USER,
       USER AS DISPLAY_VALUE
  FROM MATERIAL_DATA MD
 INNER JOIN MATERIAL_OWNER_DATA MOD
       ON MD.USER = MOD.OWNER
```

3. Added a process called "save interactive grid data" to make the grid editable
4. Added an assign user column to the interactive grid.
5. Made the assign_user column editable and changed it to a select list.

```
SELECT
    T1.DISPLAY_VALUE as DISPLAY_VALUE
FROM (
        ( SELECT
            TM.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || TM.LAST_NAME as DISPLAY_VALUE,
            upper(TM.NUMBER) as RETURN_VALUE,
            1 as ORD
        FROM 
            TEAM_MEMBERS TM
        WHERE
            TM.NUMBER IS NOT NULL
            AND TM.BOOL = 'Y'
        )
        UNION ALL
        ( SELECT
            'Not Required' as DISPLAY_VALUE,
            'Not Required' as RETURN_VALUE,
            0 as ORD
        FROM DUAL
        )
    ORDER BY 3, 1
) T1
```

6. Added the assign_user column to my interactive grid's select statement.

So far as I have searched I have not seen a step-by-step way to add the select list to the grid. It's possible I've oversimplified my process but this is the best way I could describe it. If answering this is too cumbersome a link to a good source would also be appreciated.

My company won't allow the use of css or javascript so this has to be done strictly with sql and what's already available in apex_oracle.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you posted what stands behind "The specific error I'm getting is the display_value isn't in the source data so something about how I'm trying to do this is wrong."

Comment: @Littlefoot I updated my question, but I'm still new to this. So it's difficult to add context to my specific problem. I think it's most likely I am missing a simple step to the implementation but I don't know what all the steps are.

Comment: Well, LoV query must contain exactly two values: display value (e.g. "name") and return value (e.g. "ID"). I don't know whether your query contains that or not.

Comment: It might be useful to create a temporary workspace on apex.oracle.com with a very simple test case on the emp/dept schema to illustrate your issue. You can then share the credentials for a testuser here.

Comment: What is your version of apex ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie 20.1

Comment: @Littlefoot I have added my query for my assign_user column

Comment: @KoenLostrie I'll try doing that then. Maybe it will help me figure out how to do it.

Comment: The 2nd query you posted should be `SELECT t1.display_value, t1.return_value FROM (...) t1` (at least, looks like to me).

Comment: @Littlefoot that seems to have fixed it. I can at least see my page now without an error message popping up. How do I give you credit for the answer? (New to stack overflow)

Comment: Great! Credits, as usually, are given by accepting or upvoting helpful answers (the one I posted below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd query you posted should be

```
SELECT t1.display_value, t1.return_value FROM (...) t1
```

(at least, looks like to me).